# Unexplained Numeric Output from Powershell Script

Tags: powershell, active-directory

We are working on updating scriptPath attributes in AD. We are updating employees in small groups (approximately 100-200 at a time). For this purpose I have created the following script.

```
$newScript = "foo.vbs"

# Load Employee List
$employeeList = Get-Content "NAM_logon_EmployeeList.txt"

$objDomain = New-Object System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry( "LDAP://OU=Users,DC=foobar,DC=com" )
$objSearcher = New-Object System.DirectoryServices.DirectorySearcher
$objSearcher.SearchRoot = $objDomain
$objSearcher.PageSize = 100
$objSearcher.SearchScope = "Subtree"
$colProplist = "scriptPath", "distinguishedName", "cn"

# Loop through Employee List and update the script value
ForEach ( $employee In $employeeList ) {

    $objSearcher.Filter = "(&(objectCategory=person)(objectClass=user)(mail=$employee))"
    Foreach ( $colProp in $colPropList ) {
        $objSearcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add( $colProp )
    }
    $colResults = $objSearcher.FindAll()

    ForEach ( $user In $colResults ) {
        $ntuser = $user.Properties.Item("distinguishedName")
        $myUser = $user.Properties.Item("cn")

        Script to Pushout the change
        $objUser = [ADSI]"LDAP://$($ntuser)"
        $objUser.put( "scriptPath", $newScript )
        $objUser.SetInfo()
        echo "Script Added for $($myUser)"
    }

}
```

The script works fine, but line 18:

```
$objSearcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add( $colProp )
```

Outputs numbers to the PowerShell window. One number for each Object and Attribute it adds.

```
0
1
2
Script Added for Smith, John
4
5
6
Script Added for Doe, Jane
```

etc.

I don't know why it's doing this. Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is just output that the command is outputting as it updates the object. A lot of .net objects will do this. If you don't want to see the output do the following:

```
$null = $objSearcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add( $colProp )
```

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation found [on MSDN:](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.specialized.stringcollection.add(v=vs.80).aspx)

> Return Value
>
> The zero-based index at which the new element is inserted.

So, the numbers you are seeing are the index at which the elements are being added.
For ignoring output like that, I like to do the following:

```
$objSearcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add( $colProp ) | Out-Null
```

Comment: That is a more thorough explanation than what I provided, but just to comment `$null =` or `[void]` are the best ways to handle getting rid of unwanted output. `| Out-Null` is significantly slower.

Comment: You are correct, it is.  Personally, I prefer the way it reads and I've never had an issue with performance, so I've just stuck with it.

Comment: Thank you both. I tried both ways and didn't notice a difference in performance. But I will use the '$null =' method still.